# Regular Expression for getting a version info from php file by using Delphi

Tags: regex, delphi

I have a project with Delphi and in that project I have to get a version info from a PHP file. In the PHP file there is a line that like below:

```
$app_version = 'X.X';
```

And while I am trying to get `X.X` by using

```
RegularExpression.Create('app_version.*''(?<appVersion>.*)''',[roIgnoreCase,roMultiline]);
```

I am getting

> app_version = 'X.X'

without dollar `$` and semicolon `;` signs - that's okay. But I actually only need need the

> X.X

part. So what regex rule could I use to only get version number part?

Comment: Read any book or tutorial on regular expressions. Why have you given up so readily?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've tried many times but no success but I've found another SO question that refers a page contains about Delphi's regex mechanism (PCRE). I've started to read and get more info. Thanks for advise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following regular expression:

```
\$app_version\s*=\s*["']([^"']*)["'];
```

This will match the whole expression on the line. The first group `$1` will contain the version number.

- `\$` → escapes the dollar sign, otherwise it would be "end of string"
- `\s*` → 0 or more whitespace characters
- `["']` → either `"` or `'`
- `[^"']*` → 0 or more characters which are unequal to `"` and `'`
- `(` anything `)` → matches a group to extract from a query (referred to as `$1`, `$2`, etc.)

**Here is an example in JavaScript:**

```js
var regex = /\$app_version\s*=\s*["']([^"']*)["']/g;
var text = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
var match = regex.exec(text);

while(match !== null) {
   console.log(match[1]);
   match = regex.exec(text);
}
```

```css
#main {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  $app_version   = '10.2';
  $app_version = "11.3";
  $ap_version = "10.30;
  $app_version = 9.30;
</div>
```

---

**In Delphi ([source](https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/postid/413/getting-started-with-delphi-xes-regular-expressio)):**

```
regexpr := TRegEx.Create('\$app_version\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']*)["\'];',[roIgnoreCase,roMultiline]);
match := regexpr.Match(searchMe);
if not match.Success then
begin
  WriteLn('No Match Found');
  exit;
end;

while match.Success do
begin
  WriteLn('Match : [' + match.Value + ']';
  //group 0 is the entire match, so count will always be at least 1 for a match
  if match.Groups.Count > 1 then
  begin
    for i := 1 to match.Groups.Count -1 do
      WriteLn('     Group[' + IntToStr(i) + '] : [' + match.Value + ']';
  end;
  match := match.NextMatch;
end;
```

*The code in Delphi is untested.*

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I think this code is not for using in Delphi. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alper Regex can be used in most languages and it looks pretty much the same everywhere. I've added an example in Delphi.

Comment: Thanks again for Delphi code but your code gives app_version = 'X.X'  result too. But I need to get only X.X or X.X.X vice-versa part from line that contains app_version = 'X.X' or app_version = 'X.X.X' ...

Comment: I understand that the only way to get the desired part is. First, check the line that contains app_version = 'X.X' string and extract X.X part from that string. Thank you very much for your help and effort..

Comment: Group `0` should contain the whole match, Group `1` should contain only `X.X`. Are you sure, you are checking it right? The `()` brackets select exactly the part, where the version number is and form the first group (group `1`)

Comment: First of all It works like a charm, your suggested code is more than I want, and it is so meaningful to learn more for me. Thank you very much.